# Event that triggers when slider changes value, but mouse button is not yet released

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have a slider on my page using standard html 5:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10"/>
```

When the user changes the slider value by dragging it left or right, the javascript/jquery change effect doesn't trigger until the user lets go of his mouse button. I would like to know how to create an event that triggers every time the slider has gone up 1 step, rather than the user releasing the mouse.

Using the mousedown and mousemove event and calculating the amount of pixels moved seems like a very complex and errorprone way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [input](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-input) event like

```js
$(document).on('input', '[type="range"]',
  function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" />
```